# How to generate methods in scala

Tags: scala, metaprogramming

Basically, I have a class, that has several getters that return different `Seq`s. But I need to use those collections in java code. I implemented alternate getters, that return java collections explicitly, but I want to do that in a more implicit way. Something like that:

```
class X {

     @AsJava //annotation that generates method someSeqJava: java.util.List[Int]
     def someSeq: Seq[Int] = Seq(1,2,3,4)

}
```

Or any other way. I do not want to write all those convertions myself all the time.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is similar to @BeanProperty annotation and it should be relatively easy to create a compiler plugin that does the job. In fact, from your needs, it seems you could hook the plugin after the `typer` phase (so that symbols and types are all available).

**EDIT:**

I'd suggest you to take a look at the following discussions, they might help:

- https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scala-user/UF3KUSwl1C4/discussion
- https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scala-user/H-fjKUYo_QY/discussion
- https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scala-internals/cChbFPMk82w/discussion
- https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scala-debate/Vp4uDutxQkc/discussion

Here is a short guide from the official scala website

- http://www.scala-lang.org/node/140

Comment: Is there any tutorial for creating compiler plugins for scalac?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at `JavaConversions`/`JavaConverters`.

If you want to use annotations, you might need to have a look at AspectJ.